# Link to Page with Hash locks the scroll

Tags: jquery, hash, hyperlink

I'm having a problem with linking to a specific anchor of another page.

I'll give you the specific example I'm trying to solve:

[This is the page where I'm at.](http://www.cenertec.pt/posgrad/apresentacao.php) And I link the photos of the teachers to a page containing all teachers. So, if you click in one of the photos, [you'll get here](http://www.cenertec.pt/posgrad/docentes.php#albino-reis).

Our client asked if the other teachers could disappear if the link has the hash. I said "yes of course", and made this little script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var docente = window.location.hash;
    docente = docente.replace('#','');
    if (docente != '') {
        $('.docente').hide();
        $('#' + docente).show();
    }
});
```

And it is working perfectly but another problem occured. Now, the page gets "stuck" and I can't scroll up from the anchor. It is almost as there was nothing above that "anchor".

Is there any solution to this? I really can't find anyone on the internet with the same problem as me, I may be doing something wrong.

I would really appreciate a little hand here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As you can see in the following screenshot, this is what's happenning, I can't scroll up to see the header:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I really don't get what is your actual problem? What do you mean, can't scroll? As I see, everything is works good. When I click on a picture on the top right corner, page loading, everybody removed, and only 1 shown, and I can scroll up / down with FF too.

Comment: @karacsi_maci I had a temporary fix, by removing the hash and using jquery to move the body made it work. My goal is to do this without removing the hash. It's back to normal now.